# How to bind data in siblings through typescript

Tags: angularjs, typescript

> bind value in these tow siblings child1.controller.ts and
>   child2.controller.ts

```
/*
file : 
index.html
|_app.ts
|_app.confing.ts (routing with parent.html and invoke parent controller)
  |
  |_parent.controller.ts
    parent.html
    |__ (invoke child1 Directive)
    |  |_child1.contoller.ts
    |  |_child1.html
    |
    |__(invoce child2 Directive)
       |_child2.contoller.ts
       |_child2.html

parent.html
<child1-tab></child1-tab>
<child2-tab></child2-tab>
*/
```

> parent.controller.ts

```
module app.parent{
  'use strict';
  class ParentController {
  static $inject = ["$scope"];
    constructor(public $scope)
    {
      scope.status = "Parent Controller";
    }
  }
}
```

> child1.controller.ts

```
/*child1-tab-Controller*/
module app.child1{
class child2Controller {
  comingValue :string;
  static $inject = ["$scope"];
    constructor(public $scope){
      this.comingValue = "";  //<= (I want to update it via child2.controller)
    }
  }
angular.module('myApp')
    .controller('child1Controller', child1Controller);
}
```

> child2.controller.ts

```
/*child2-tab-Controller*/
module app.child1{
class child2Controller {
  newValue:string;
  static $inject = ["$scope"];
  constructor(public $scope){
    this.newValue = "Send It to Child1"; //(newValue be send to child1Controller and set to the     comingValue field in child1Controller)
    }
  }
 angular.module('myApp')
    .controller('child2Controller', child2Controller);
}
```

> I want ot use a child2.controller->newValue  to set the
>   child1.controller->comingValue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use two-way binding

```
<child1-tab my-model="vm.model"></child1-tab>
<child2-tab my-model="vm.model"></child2-tab>
```

or you can use [angular event system](https://toddmotto.com/all-about-angulars-emit-broadcast-on-publish-subscribing/)

An another article about [communication between directives](http://blog.carbonfive.com/2015/03/25/communication-between-collaborating-directives-in-angular/) in angular.

Comment: Yes, I done this by $rootScope.$emit and $rootScope.$on. You briefly describe the two-way binding my-model="vm-model". How it works and how I use to share data. Thanks.